# Attempting to read variables from Firebase with Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to access a simple Firebase database (https://blazing-fire-6348.firebaseio.com) and store its values separately, but they're not storing properly. The code below spits out all 10's, rather than the values stored in Firebase. I don't think my issue is just scope, but Firebase syntax. The tilde's are the website url, stackoverflow just wouldn't let me post the link multiple times.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
var a = 10; var b = 10; var c = 10;

var dataRef = new Firebase("~~~/a");
dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) { 
   a = snapshot.val();
   // alert(a);
 });
var dataRef = new Firebase("~~~/b");
dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) { if(snapshot.val() != null){
    b = snapshot.val();
   // alert(b);
} });
var dataRef = new Firebase("~~~/c");
dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) { if(snapshot.val() != null){
    c = snapshot.val();
    // alert(c);
} });

alert(a); alert(b); alert(c);`
```

`

Comment: If you enable the commented out alerts, those will show the correct values. Did you try?

Comment: Yes, they will. I'm looking for a way to access the variables outside of the dataRef.on function.

Comment: As the `alert`s at the bottom show, you can **access** the variables anywhere. But they won't have the value from remote Firebase, until after the `dataRef.on('value'` callback fires. It comes from the asynchronous nature of AJAX calls. Given that the behavior you are seeing is completely expected, maybe you can describe in another way what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that the `on` call in Firebase is asynchronous:

```
var dataRef = new Firebase("~~~/a");
dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) { 
    // this code will only execute once the server *returns* a value for a
});
// this code will execute straight after the call to the server has *started*
```

Your code will trigger three calls to the Firebase server, each of which can take some varying time to complete.

Therefore you cannot simply `alert` all three results at the end of the script and expect them to have the value from the server. All you know at the point in the script is that all calls to the server have **started**. There is no guarantee that any or all of them have **completed** though.

Instead you'll have to use a strategy to determine when all calls have completed.

A simple way to do this in your example:

```
var a, b, c;

var dataRef = new Firebase("~~~/a");
dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) { 
   a = snapshot.val();
   if (a && b && c) alert(a+b+c);
 });
var dataRef = new Firebase("~~~/b");
dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) { if(snapshot.val() != null){
    b = snapshot.val();
   if (a && b && c) alert(a+b+c);
} });
var dataRef = new Firebase("~~~/c");
dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) { if(snapshot.val() != null){
    c = snapshot.val();
   if (a && b && c) alert(a+b+c);
} });
```

Each callback (the function that receives the snapshot, that you pass into `on`) check whether the others have also completed. Only when all values have been set, will it alert their sum.

Comment: Note that this (very excellent) example will only trigger the alert if none of the values are null.